# Keep query-string on every link

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I want to personalize my Symfony project by letting the user choose a city in a selectbox in the top navi. For that I got a query string e.g. ?city=berlin that I fetch in my controllers and filter the results with.

Is there an easy way to keep that query string on every url alive or would you prefer an other solution without a query string? Maybe with cookies?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Storing in sessions would be a good choice in your case !

Comment: @IrfanAhmed it's not a good idea since 1. you cannot share the urls with a city set (city is no personalization, see my answer below) 2. google bots will certainly not add stateful session content to any index, like two bots crawling your site differently, getting different content from identical urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than talking about cookies is the question about stateful or stateless session. Cookies is just the implementation of mapping the client to the session.

Let's say you have a visitor on one city-parametrized page. What do you except your page to look like, when someone copies the url and shares it with others? city is *not* any personal state, although you mentioned *personalized* above (e.g. having responsive pages where I can set the font to 120% size or setting higher contrast, would be a personalized configuration I actually don't want to share in the url).

*city* is part of the state of the page and not the session, thus we want city to be part of the url. Define a prefix route like `/{city}` and import another yml with that prefix (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes).

Every time you generate an url with a city you have to set it. You could do this manually or create some `CityDecoratedRouter implements RouterInterface` getting `@router` and `@request_stack` injected and appends the `city` parameter to all `parameter`-arrays in `generate()` calls.

@EvgeniyKuzmin's answer is imho too much magic no one expects. When dealing with those routes having a `city` parameter it's better to read it in the code, that the routes are treated differently. Of course you also have to define some new `city_path` function for twig, which uses our `CityDecoratedRouter`.

Comment: Hey, thank you, I think this is how I want to do it.. :) But how can I make the prefix optional? What I got now are routes like /{city}/{category}/{id}.
How could I make the city optional, so if no city is selected, items of all citys are displayed?

Comment: Have no clue how the router could recognize when the first prefix is {category} and when its {city}, because of that my first idea was to use GET querys for the city.

Comment: you can use `{category}/{id}` as route and set `city` in `defaults`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stick user to some condition base on route path (I will advice you use SEO urls instead of GET query) and then use it as stick filter for some behavior on other pages, then you can do such listener:

BaseKernelEvents:

```
namespace App\CoreBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

abstract class BaseKernelEvents
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * Initializes a new instance of the KernelEvents class.
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, Router $router)
    {   
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /*
     * Store and get value by route param passed to uri to request and session
     */
    protected function storeParam(GetResponseEvent $event, $name, $default = 'none')
    {
        /* @var $request \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        /* @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // instead of attributes you can get query from request here
        $value = $request->attributes->get($name);
        if (!$value) {
            $value = $session->get($name, $default);
        }

        return $this->setValues($event, $name, $value);
    }

    /*
     * Set name/value to request context and session
     */
    protected function setValues(GetResponseEvent $event, $name, $value)
    {
        /* @var $request \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $context = $this->router->getContext();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->set($name, $value);
        $context->setParameter($name, $value);

        return $value;
    }
}
```

KernelEvents:

```
namespace LaMelle\ContentSectionBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

use App\CoreBundle\Listener\BaseKernelEvents;

class KernelEvents extends BaseKernelEvents
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType())
        {
            $contentsectionSlug = $this->storeParam($event, 'city');

            // DO SOMETHINK BASE ON FILTER
            // LIKE CREATE GLOBAL TWIG VAR WITH FILTER VALUE 
            /* @var \Twig_Environment $globals */
            $globals = $this->container->get('twig');
            $globals->addGlobal('city', $contentsectionSlug);

        }
    }
}
```

So in shown example you will have 'city' be filled from session until you will visit route that change 'city' to other value